# How to disable in render just one object and not the entire collection in blender 2.8?

Tags: rendering

Earlier in outliner 3 options were available for each object one of which was disable render. Now only one option is available for each object. Basically how to disable render for single object inside of collection

Answer (score 2):

In the outliner there is a filter option which allows you to enable the *Restriction Toggles* that aren't displayed by default which includes *Disable in Renders* (camera icon). Once you have it enabled you can disable any object or collection from being rendered by clicking on the camera icon behind it in the outliner.

[image: Filter restriction toggles]

[image: Disable render]

Comment: Thanks rjg .. I was wondering why they will remove it..

Comment: @PrashantKumar You're welcome. They wouldn't remove such an important feature. I currently can't find the discussion on the patch or commits that introduced hiding the restriction toggles by default, but I'm assuming it's to reduce the number of icons in the UI when they aren't needed. This change has confused *a lot* of people since it was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to make this object one hundred per cent transparent.