# Hi poly to low poly looks fine in viewport but not good after F12 render

Tags: rendering, materials, texture-baking

I'm new to Blender (v2.8) but have done a fair amount of work in 3dsMax, at present purely as a hobbyist. I have been following the Anvil tutorial from Blender Guru and have successfully, or so it would appear in the viewport, baked the low poly version. In the viewport all appears to be well (unfinished as you can see), [image: base colour material applied]however when I try a render using F12 I get this result. [image: F12 render result]I thought it was maybe my ray distance etc but varying settings make little difference. Pulling my hair out with this as a noob, would really appreciate some help please.

Comment: You have hidden the other anvil objects in the viewport but not in the render. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152955/how-to-disable-in-render-just-one-object-and-not-the-entire-collection-in-blende

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much... I think I need to get an actual book :)

Comment: Books can't really keep up with the pace of development. I'd suggest the official manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Many thanks again, I do have the manual but, as ever, last resort and all that. Now I shall read it properly :)