# blank white square appears only when rendering

Tags: rendering, materials

Whenever I render an image that appears. It shows up nowhere else in my scene or view port.

Comment: You may have hidden an object in your viewport, but not in your render. Take a look at: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152955/how-to-disable-in-render-just-one-object-and-not-the-entire-collection-in-blende

Answer (score 1):

When part of an image is transparent, a checker board pattern is shown.

With the background set as transparent, you will see this in the render, This can also be visible in the viewport when it is set to render preview.

[image: display of transparent background]

In evee and cycles, the transparent background setting can be found in the film panel of the render properties.

[image: film options]

It is also possible to get the same effect for a single object. For this you need to use a holdout shader for the object, or setup compositing nodes to cut it out.

[image: a transparent object]