# Plane in Render not visible in Object Mode

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, glass

Thanks in advance for any help. I am following Andrew's Donut/Cup tut on youtube using 2.8.1 and had a render problem.  Here is a snap of my Object Mode 
[image: Object Mode with all objects of interest visible]

And here is the same view in render mode.  The 'pink' plane/table is not visible, instead I have a gray plane intersecting my cup which I cannot find in Object Mode.
[image: Render Mode]

Why do I have this plane and why is my cup, in Object Mode (Principled BSDF, Transmiission=1, Roughness=0) have what looks like an HDRI country scene in LookDev mode?

Comment: Note: the donut is floating above the cup, just to move it out of the way, otw it would be intersected too by the gray plane

Comment: You've hidden the object in the viewport by clicking on the eye icon in the outliner. This doesn't hide it in the render though. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152955/how-to-disable-in-render-just-one-object-and-not-the-entire-collection-in-blende

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have another plane in your scene, it's just **not showing in the viewport**.

In your **outliner** check these options and look at all the collections you have, there is a plane there **not visible** but **renderable**. You can disable by object or entire collections.

*Nice donut btw!*

[image: Outliner]
More about it at: [Blender Docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner.html#collections)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 planes from what I can see in your outliner. I'd bet that 'plane.001' is the pink one you see in the viewport. The plane that's cutting through the cup (and it looks like the donut is sitting on) may be in the donut collection - it's showing there are 2 items there and it's not expanded.

The reason you can't see it in the main viewport could be that at some point you hid it and forgot about it. See if alt-H brings it back. If not, check out the donut collection and make sure that the outliner shows it as visible.