# My render doesn't look like my shading tab

Tags: rendering, shaders, hdri

[image]

I want to render this scene (white walls, white reflective floor, wooden table, HDRI background) but it doesn't want to render like I made it. Can anyone help please?

Comment: You have hidden some objects in the viewport, but not in the render. Take a look at [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152955/how-to-disable-in-render-just-one-object-and-not-the-entire-collection-in-blende).

Comment: You are right! Thanks, stupid mistake by me