# Strange artifacts using Cycles

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

When I render in cycles i'm getting these weird artifacts. They look like surfaces that have been translated, scaled up, generally funked up.

This model is probably a mess under the surface. It looks like some of them correspond to cutters so I tried disabling cutters from view, but same effect.

It only shows up when rendering in cycles, nothing in ever. Any thought much appreciated. This is my second tutorial after The Donut so probably a lot of bad habits coming out.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps these are objects that have been hidden in the viewport (eye icon) but not in the [render (camera icon)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152955/how-to-disable-in-render-just-one-object-and-not-the-entire-collection-in-blende)? There's also a silver object at the front intersecting one of the arms in the first render. This might be hard to answer without taking a look at the file (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). That being said, if this is the second model you've ever made, I'm thoroughly impressed.

Comment: That looks to me like a modifier with different settings for render than for preview.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Yeah I've been looking for hidden objects, but no luck.

And I will look through the modifiers to see if there's any funny business going on there.

Any other thoughts much appreciated.